# Speed up HTML form development

Tags: html, forms, ide, wufoo

I have to build an web app with a large amount of forms. Does anyone have a favourite tool to speed this development up?  This isn't complicated but writing them by hand will take me ages...

I've used [wufoo](http://wufoo.com) in the past and like the interface, so short of any other suggestions I'll probably go with that

Answer (score 1):

A similar tool to Wufoo is [Form Assembly](http://www3.formassembly.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a [JSON-based form generator](http://jameslab.moveable.com/JSONForm/), but it's in its early stages. No wysiwyg, but an easy data structure to follow.